# DefineProjection_management - "Object: Error in executing tool'

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I included
coordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(4283) and it works when I point the workspace path to a GHB file. However I get an error below when including multiple GHB folders into the workspace z:/temp.

name 'inData' is not defined.

My code is below. Can somebody suggest a fix?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "Z:/temp"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*', "ALL")

for file in fcs:
   print arcpy.env.workspace, file

try:
    for file in fcs:
      inData = file
     coordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(4283)

 # updates/overwrites coordinate system information and map projection stored with a dataset
# accepts dataset and coordinate system information
      arcpy.DefineProjection_management(inData, coordinateSystem)

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
   print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
   arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
except Exception as e:
   print e.args[0]
   arcpy.AddError(e.args[0])
```

The ghb folders and shape files are stored in their folders as per the screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's GDA94 isn't it? Perhaps coordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(4283) would work better. 4283 is the EPSG/SRID code for GDA94/Geographic http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4283/ I note that your indentation is inconsistent, the try: should be indented but that may be in your copy/paste. Is it possible there's a broken shapefile in that folder? I've seen much mischief and face-palm caused by a missing .dbf or .shx file.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Something I find useful when presenting questions here and testing is to remove any try/except statements because they can mask Python errors that are often useful when trying to debug.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out why coordinateSystem's value contains two GEOGCS objects and a space. Try taking out the second GEOGCS object. Are you trying to add a vertical coordinate system too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your coordinate system variable into a spatial reference object.  Do this with arcpy.SpatialReference(EPSG Num or Name) - 4283 for GDA94.

If you need a custom spatial reference, create it in ArcMap and save as a .prj file.  You can then point to the prj file like this:

```
arcpy.SpatialReference("C:/Data/SpatialRef/Custom_GDA94.prj")
```